# HIVE on Spark Issue

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql, hadoop2

I am trying to configure Hive on Spark but even after trying for 5 days i am not getting any solution..

Steps followed:

1.After spark installation,going in hive console and setting below proeprties

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set spark.master=spark://INBBRDSSVM294:7077;
set spark.executor.memory=2g;             
set spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
```

2.Added spark -asembly jar in hive lib.

3.When running `select count(*) from table_name` I am getting below error:

```
2016-08-08 15:17:30,207 ERROR [main]: spark.SparkTask (SparkTask.java:execute(131)) 
- Failed to execute spark task, with exception
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException (Failed to create spark client.)'
```

Hive version: 1.2.1
Spark version: tried with 1.6.1,1.3.1 and 2.0.0
Would appreciate if any one can suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

You can download spark-1.3.1 src from spark download website and try to build spark-1.3.1 without hive version using:

```
./make-distribution.sh --name "hadoop2-without-hive" --tgz "-Pyarn,hadoop-provided,hadoop-2.4" -Dhadoop.version=2.7.1 -Dyarn.version=2.7.1 –DskipTests
```

Then copy spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.7.1.jar to hive/lib folder.

And follow https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started#HiveonSpark:GettingStarted-SparkInstallation to set necessary properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to pay attention to which versions are compatible. If you choose Hive 1.2.1, I advise you to use Spark 1.3.1. You can see the version compatibility list [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started).

The mistake you have is a general mistake. You need to start Spark and see what errors the Spark Workers says. However, have you already copied the hive-site.xml to spark/conf?